# How to compute the most correlated variable between multiple variables(except itself)? And how to simplify the codes by using loops or map functions?

Tags: r, loops

Let's say I have a data frame like this:

```
data.frame(replicate(10,sample(10:100,1000,rep=TRUE)))
```

```
     X1 X2 X3  X4  X5 X6 X7  X8 X9 X10
1    45 77 74  76  56 26 49  96 31  33
2    48 27 82  13  17 90 83  94 82  80
3    60 48 84  39  23 78 44  36 33  26
4    17 65 67  58  43 86 58  44 32  76
5    99 38 28  73  32 85 92  17 87  85
6    19 31 18  46  87 88 10  16 40  79
7    68 82 58 100  71 86 16  46 43  41
8    33 23 83  30  74 29 79  29 78  31
```

For each variable, how do I compute its most positively correlated variable(except itself) and how do I simplify my codes by using loops or one of the `map()` functions. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider adding a small sample of your data (the one in the picture is enough, but in order to help we need to be able to copy and paste). Also, it is very useful for us if you show what you have tried and where you have failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cor` function to calculate the correlation of each variable with every other variable. Replace diagonals with 0 and use `max.col` to get the highest correlated variable.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(10:100,1000,rep=TRUE)))
cor_df <- cor(df)
diag(cor_df) <- 0
max.col(cor_df)
#[1] 5 6 4 3 6 2 5 4 2 1

#Or creating a dataframe with column names
result <- data.frame(var = names(df), cor_var = names(df)[max.col(cor_df)])
result
#   var cor_var
#1   X1      X5
#2   X2      X6
#3   X3      X4
#4   X4      X3
#5   X5      X6
#6   X6      X2
#7   X7      X5
#8   X8      X4
#9   X9      X2
#10 X10      X1
```